# is there a way make a character to be part of two matches not only one

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex: `1(0+)1`

and I'm testing against this value: `1010010001`,

I'm expecting that I have three matches: `101`, `1001`, `10001` but the matches that I got are only: `101`, `10001`.

the second `1` should be part of the two matches: `101` and `1001`.

is there a way make a character to be part of two matches ?

https://regex101.com/r/oNfdFU/1

Comment: Regex implementations vary quite a lot; where are you using this (what programming language, library, or tool)?

Comment: I've used `C# & .NET` it gave me the same result that I got on `regex101`

Comment: Note that you could simply match `10+` and then append each resulting string with `'1'`, assuming you know the string has a valid form (the string begins and ends with a one and there are one or more zeros between each pair of ones).

Comment: @CarySwoveland There's nothing in the question that defines a "valid form" for the input. For all we know, they might be searching for this pattern in a 100MB text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do this in C#.  We can find all matches on the regex pattern `10+(?=1)`.  This uses a lookahead at the end of the pattern to assert a trailing `1`, but note that the trailing `1` does not actually get *consumed* in each match.  It gets consumed in the start of the following match.  Then, to build the actual output match, we need to append a `1` to the end of each match.

```
string input = "1010010001";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"10+(?=1)");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found a match: {0}1", match.Value);
}
```

This prints:

```
Found a match: 101
Found a match: 1001
Found a match: 10001
```

Comment: Considering that you are not also confirming that the string has the desired form (i.e., matches `^(?:10+)+1$`) I don't see why you need the lookahead. Isn't `10+` enough?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The lookahead proves that *each match* has the desired form. If you just match `10+` and append a 1, you will invent non-existent matches in a string like "10201" or "10099" or indeed just "10". There's nothing in the question that constrains the whole string, only a single example input.

Comment: @IMSoP, you are assuming that the string might be `'a01010b0110010c'` in which case `'101'` and `1001` (but not `'11'`) are to be matched. In view of the OP's example is your assumption about the "desired form" more reasonable than mine? Regardless, my point is that the lookahead is not needed  if the string is known to match `^(?:10+)+1$`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't think it's safe to assume one way or the other without asking the OP, but the more general solution is applicable to both cases anyway, and is likely to be useful to other readers of the site. Given only one sample input, we _could_ just hard-code the output, but that doesn't really teach anyone anything, other than how to write better questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capturing lookahead to capture overlapping matching groups.

In this case:

```
(?=(10+1))
^ ^      ^     look ahead
    ^  ^       fixed '1' The second can overlap (the first never will on LH)
     ^         '0' one or more times also can overlap
    ^   ^      capture what is seen in the look ahead
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NoAfwq/1/)

The lookahead is looking ahead and capturing in one step. It then increments by one character and tries again -- so moving through the string by each left hand `1`.

Same regex works in C#

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%2810%2B1%29%29&i=1010010001)

Or, in C#:

```
string input = "1010010001";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?=(10+1))");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach(Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found a match: {0}", match.Groups[1]);
    }
```

Prints:

```
Found a match: 101
Found a match: 1001
Found a match: 10001
```

---

BTW: .NET allows variable width lookBEHINDS so you can also do:

```
(?<=(10+1))
```

But that is fairly unique to .NET. PCRE and most other regex flavors require fixed length strings for look behinds...

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%2810%2B1%29%29&i=1010010001)

Comment: OK, but the OP seems to be using .NET, not Perl.

Comment: Same regex works in C# [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3d%2810%2b1%29%29&i=1010010001)

Comment: It's a shame the question has been marked as a duplicate, because I think your explanation is clearer than the ones previously posted.